# Can I use my ISP's dhcp server as part of my local PXE boot configuration?

Tags: centos, dhcp, router, pxe

I am trying to configure a network PXE boot server on my local network. I am currently following the Centos7 guide at http://www.tecmint.com/install-pxe-network-boot-server-in-centos-7. One of the required network services is DHCP. My ISP is AT&T Uverse and the router's model is 5268ACFXN. The router already has DHCP configured. Will there be an issue if my configuration file points to my router for the DHCP services, or will I have to setup my own local DHCP server, and disable the DHCP service on my router.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need setup your own local DHCP server and disable the DHCP service on your router. Use ISC dhcp server for it.

Don't forget add dhcp options default rote and DNS name server. They must be your router internal ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed to disable the DHCP/DNS services of your ISP modem/router.

For the TFTP service to work some configuration/fields have to be supported by the DHCP services, that your ISP equipment won't let you configure ; namely the attributes:

- `next-server` that tells the client in the DHCP answer from which TFTP server it will have to download the files;
- `filename` in the lease that will tell per machine/MAC which files to download.

Whilst more challenging, it might also be more educative, and more useful for bigger infra-structures to setup BIND+ISC DHCP+tftpboot for this service.

From the Debian manuals:

[4.5. Preparing Files for TFTP Net Booting](https://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/amd64/ch04s05.html.en)

> ```
> group {
>   next-server 192.168.1.3;
>   host tftpclient {
> # tftp client hardware address
>   hardware ethernet  00:10:DC:27:6C:15;
>   filename "pxelinux.0";
>  }
>  }
> ```
>
> setting up BOOTP with ISC dhcpd is really easy, because it treats
>   BOOTP clients as a moderately special case of DHCP clients. Some
>   architectures require a complex configuration for booting clients via
>   BOOTP. If yours is one of those, read the section Section 4.5.2,
>   “Setting up a DHCP server”. In that case, you will probably be able to
>   get away with simply adding the allow bootp directive to the
>   configuration block for the subnet containing the client, and restart
>   dhcpd with /etc/init.d/dhcpd3-server restart.